# what code I need change to help me remove remove index.php from my website url?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url, seo

Below is my nginx.conf's server code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TAb8.png)

I have already try add below code,but it's dosent's work.

```
location / {
     if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
     }
}
```

```
location / {
    if (-f $request_filename/index.html){
        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }
    if (-f $request_filename/index.php){
        rewrite (.*) $1/index.php;
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename){
        rewrite (.*) /index.php;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use rewrites for that.  You only need to set the index document.

```
location / {
    index index.php;
}
```

See the Nginx documentation: [Serving Static Content | NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#root-directory-and-index-files)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already try it .  But  it's  still not  work.